# How to diagnose and / or troubleshoot keyboard shortcut issues?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am having problems assigning keyboard shortcuts, particularly with the super key. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on an ASUS N56VJ hardware, my <kbd>Super</kbd> key works as it's default use but when I try to assign it to key combinations it doesn't work. Two cases where it is not working are:

1. I want to assign a combination of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to open my home folder. I am doing this from the keyboard shortcuts menu and it allows me to assign it but the combination does not respond.
2. I'm also trying to assign <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to open my Guake terminal. This I am doing from the Quake preferences menu. Again it allows me to assign it but the combination does not work.

How can I go about diagnosing and troubleshooting this issue and in general any keyboard shortcut that does not work?

Comment: `xev` can help you to troubleshoot. It's a X11 util (from the package `x11-utils` ;-) )
Lauch it from the terminal and it will display on stdout every X11 events. Tell us what it tells when you press your key combinations. (hint : you should hit Ctrl-C before attempting cut and paste on the output).